# Is there way to use Nest JS with Sapper (Svelte)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, svelte, sapper

I've been looking for the past few days, but I haven't found a single sample code or article that discusses how to combine (*not separate them as API Service & Frontend Service*) [Nest JS](https://docs.nestjs.com/) with [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev/) (*Svelte*). Does anyone have any references in this regard?

Comment: How do you want to integrate them? You can build and deploy a NestJS API, and consume it from a separate Sapper app. Is that close to what you want?

Comment: Not. I want to combine the two things in one application or instance.

Comment: [Marcio Koji Carvalho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4883462) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66214703) saying "[Nest.js Sapper working example](https://github.com/walker-walks/nest.js-sapper-example)
Dirty but working example"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with the same issue and found this [template repository on GitHub](https://github.com/frontend-templates-world/nest-svelte). I've tested it out and it works pretty well.

The only "downside" is that it uses Svelte instead of Sapper.